# Вывод массива

Tags: массивы

```
<?php
//Определение Возраста Пользователя по дате Рождения и Вывод с БД MySQL на PHP!

include ("../config.php");
$result_all_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users",$db); //извлекаем дату рождения по идентификатору пользователей
$myrow_all_users = mysql_fetch_array($result_all_users);

$birthday = $myrow_all_users['birthday'];

//Получаем дату для сравнения 
$left_arr = explode("-", "$birthday"); 
$right_arr  = explode("-", date("Y-m-d"));

//Разница в днях 
$return['d'] = $right_arr[2] - $left_arr[2]; 
if ( $return['d'] < 0 ) { 
  $right_arr[1]--; 
  $temp = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $left_arr[1], 1, $left_arr[0])); // "t" - число дней в месяце 
  $return['d'] = $temp - $left_arr[2] + $right_arr[2]; 
}

//Разница в месяцах 
$return['m'] = $right_arr[1] - $left_arr[1]; 
if ( $return['m'] < 0 ) { 
  $right_arr[0]--; 
  $return['m'] += 12; 
}

//Разница в годах 
$return['y'] = $right_arr[0] - $left_arr[0];

//Вывод без массива - работает отлично!
echo ("Васи Иванову $return[y] год <br/>");

do {
//Вывод массива - не выводит количество лет!
    printf("<a href='users.php?id=%s'>%s %s</a> год<br/>",$myrow_all_users['id'],$myrow_all_users['name'],$myrow_all_users['surname'],$return['y']);
    }
while($myrow_all_users = mysql_fetch_array($result_all_users));

?>
```

ПОМОГИТЕ ВЫВЕСТИ КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЛЕТ КАЖ

Comment: "ЛЕТ КАЖ" - ? Подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: ПОМОГИТЕ ВЫВЕСТИ КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЛЕТ КАЖДОГО ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ В МАССИВЕ?
ВЫВОД БЕЗ МАССИВА РАБОТАЕТ НА УРА!)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("<a href='users.php?id=%s'>%s %s</a> %s год<br/>",$myrow_all_users['id'],$myrow_all_users['name'],$myrow_all_users['surname'],$return['y']);
```

Comment: и что здесь изменилось?(

Comment: да, я там после закрывающего тега </a> пропустил %s, но так выводит скока лет первому пользователю во всем массиве! например первому пользователю 21, выводит что всем пользователям по 21 год!